# compressing jQuery code and making it more dynamic

Tags: jquery, dynamic

So I have the following code that effects some footer tags with the cookie plug-in. Now I'm a bit of a n00b, and can't figure out a way to make the code more dynamic. Now I have to copy each variable and make a new for each "exit". I wonder if it is possible to make the `if` statement more dynamic?
Note that each `#exit` is on a different subpage, whom all are linked to the main.js file.

Link: http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/index.html

The jQuery-code:

```
$('#exit1').click(function(){
$('#collection1').css('color', '#ff63ff');
$.cookie('foundHeart1', 'found', {
    path: '/'
});
});

var foundHeart1 = $.cookie('foundHeart1');

if (foundHeart1 == 'found'){
    $('#collection1').addClass('found');
};

    $('#exit2').click(function(){
$('#collection2').css('color', '#ff63ff');
$.cookie('foundHeart2', 'found', {
    path: '/'
});
});

var foundHeart2 = $.cookie('foundHeart2');

if (foundHeart2 == 'found'){
    $('#collection2').addClass('found');
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this by adding meta-data to the element, and giving them all a shared class rather than an id

So, say your current `#exit1`, `#exit2` etc are links, give them a class of `exit` and add some extra `data-*` to be used later:

```
<a href="#" class="exit" data-key="1">Exit</a>
<a href="#" class="exit" data-key="2">Exit</a>
```

Then you can just have 1 handler that does every exit:

```
$('.exit').click(function(){
    var key = $(this).data('key');
    $('#collection' + key).css('color', '#ff63ff');
    $.cookie('foundHeart' + key, 'found', {
        path: '/'
    });
});
```

Now you might have 2 pages, all using the same code for the exit button, but it look slike you want to check them all on each page load, something like this should suffice:

```
var maxCookie = 2; // or whatever your number of hearts is
for(var i=1;i<=maxCookie;i++){
   if($.cookie('foundHeart' + i) == 'found'){
       $('#collection' + i).addClass('found')
    }
}
```

Comment: this would be my approach.. i just don't understand the cookies in original code.. they were not wrapped in click handler, so you might need to process them all

Comment: @MichalKlouda - Nah, im pretty sure the whole of the OP code is written in a `$(document).ready` which  means hes trying to determine which cookie has been set. You probably only need to process the one associated with the current page's exit button. See updated answer. (Might be wrong though!)

Comment: Cool, my only consern is: will the it work on all pages since the ".exits"  is on different subpages?

Comment: @CarlPapworth - Not sure what you mean. What's a "subpage"? The last block of code will only work if a) there is only 1 `.exit` on the current page and b) if it is the one with the right data to read the cookie and set the collection's class.

Comment: Yes it is within a `$(document).ready`statement :)
@Jamiec: well, there in different .html documents so to say... so different pages on the site. If you click the link wou will see the "hearts" at the bottom of the page, those should be effected and if one has been "found", the class-change should stay on each page...

Example: if .exit has been clicked on three different pages, there should be three pink hearts permanently in the footer!

Comment: @CarlPapworth - See updated answer - its much simpler now with only 1 piece of data on the exit button - the key (or index) of that heart.

Comment: `i` is a [loop control variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variable#computer_programming) (I know you're trying to learn, but thats really, really, really basic stuff)

Comment: Cool, well, I can't say that my learning process goes through a step-by-step-handbook exactly :) Thanks for the extra info!